# Pipeline artifacts in .NET client libraries for Azure DevOps Services (and TFS)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Originally posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/6403).

We are using [.NET client libraries for Azure DevOps Services (and TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops) in some custom tools. BuildHttpClient.GetArtifactContentZipAsync does not work for the new [pipeline artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic). Which HttpClient do I use to download this type of artifacts?

Comment: No, still looking for a solution.

Comment: Are you using this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.webapi.buildhttpclientbase.getartifactcontentzipasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet#Microsoft_TeamFoundation_Build_WebApi_BuildHttpClientBase_GetArtifactContentZipAsync_System_Int32_System_String_System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_), Any error message? since you said it is not working.

Comment: Yes, I am using this API. The error says that no such artifact exists.

Answer (score 0):

> Pipeline artifacts in .NET client libraries for Azure DevOps Services (and TFS)

I am afraid there is no such .NET client libraries for Pipeline artifacts.

As we could to know, the [Pipeline artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

> Pipeline artifacts provide a way to **share files between stages in a
>   pipeline** or between different pipelines.

When we share the files between stages in a pipeline, it just like a "copy" inside in the pipeline, it is more like a copy instruction of windows. So, this operation does not have the client's libraries to implement it.

You could implicitly get related information from the document [Keep in mind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publishing-artifacts):

> - If you plan to consume the artifact from a job running on a different operating system or file system, you must ensure all file paths in the artifact are valid for the target environment. For example, a file name containing a \ or * character will typically
>     fail to download on Windows.

On the other hand, I have checked the source code for this [azure-pipelines-tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/PublishPipelineArtifactV1), there is also no source code to implement it here.

Hope this helps.